# Retrieving data from Oracle db in asp.net mvc using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm a newbie with less than a year of experience. Sadly I have nobody to ask in my company, so I'm spending a lot of time to find out what's wrong.

I just finished asp.net mvc project and try to change only DB
From: SQL Server
To: Oracle

In my original project, I retrieved data like this from SQL Server. Works well.

```
using (var haksaContext = new HaksaContext())
{
    try{
        var haksa = haksaContext.HaksaMembers.Where(m => m.stnt_numb == model.Stnt_Numb).ToList();
        if (haksa.Count == 1){
```

My code has no problem in SQL Server so I searched and installed Nuget package for Oracle, Oracle developer tools for VS 2015 and I successfully added Oracle DB to my Server Explorer. And target table in OracleDB has the same column name, structure.(actually there are some difference in data type like int <-> number)

If I query using Query Window, I can select from target table. Seems no problem here:

[image: If I query using Query Window, I can select from target table. Seems no problem here.]

I copied original dbcontext(HaksaContext) to make OracleContext and modified it like next photo

```
public class HaksaContext : DbContext //-> OracleContext
    {
        public HaksaContext() : base("HaksaContext") { } //-> OracleContext
        public DbSet<UniversityMember> HaksaMembers{get; set;} //Didn't fix here because table structure is the same
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
```

Then I modified the linq part:

```
using (var haksaContext = new OracleContext())
{
    try{
        var haksa = haksaContext.HaksaMembers.Where(m => m.stnt_numb == model.Stnt_Numb).ToList();
        if (haksa.Count == 1){
```

But it doesn't retrieve data, and haksa. Count is 0

I tried debug and found out the connection string is strange. In my web.config I used this

```
<add name="OracleContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=myid;Password=mypw;(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=targetdbIP)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=haksadb)))" />
```

[image: connectionString, DataSource]

It's far from my connectionString in web.config.. where is this connectionString came from..

```
Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|OraleContext.mdf;Initial Catalog=OraleContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

If I debug from original project that part shows exactly the same connectionString as I typed in web.config

Comment: so the code is not throwing any exceptions?

Comment: also the connection string for Oracle is going to look a lot different that the sql server one.  Oracle uses a tnsnames.ora file to map connections to to specific oracle serve instances.  The connection string you posted is a complete entry that you would find in the tnsnames.ora file.  Keeping this information in the connection string and not a tnsnames file is a plus in my book because it makes you less reliant on the oracle client.

Comment: No sir, it doesn't show exception before it shows that weird Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;~~  
After that step, it throws exception like Enumerable didn't return anything. I think it is just because of the connectionString in the picture. No idea where is that came from xd

Answer (score 0):

By default Entity Framework uses the connection string with the same name as your DbContext.

In your case, change the connection string to

```
<add name="HaksaContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="..." />
```

I know it's probably too late :)